# Insert query result from one MS-Access database to another using ADO

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access, ado

I would be grateful if somebody give me advice on how to put result of query from one database to another database.

I can perform select query on one database but how can I move/save that result (data) in another database ? I'm using ADO components in Rad Studio - Delphi on local *.mdb and *.accdb databases. Any tips ? Thanks to all for your responses.

Comment: Can you poste what did you try? and also sample data table structure

Comment: Is the destination database also ms-access (I assume it is)? does the destination database/table exists or not? are their structures identical? does the source have to be from an ADO Dataset/Query first? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a special syntax for the SQL you use to select the data rows you want to copy, as follows:

I have a first database `d:\aaad7\ado\test.mdb` containing an Access table `ATable` containing one character column, `ANAME`.  I also have a second, empty database `d:\aaad7\ado\dest.mdb`.

The following code copies the table `ATable` to the second database.

```
  AdoQueryCopy.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * INTO ATable IN "D:\aaad7\ado\dest.mdb" FROM ATable';
  AdoQueryCopy.ExecSql;
```

where `AdoQueryCopy` is a TADOQuery which has a connection string which points to  `d:\aaad7\ado\test.mdb`.

**Important** If you want to open the copy of `ATable` in `d:\aaad7\ado\dest.mdb`, you need to close the connection which `AdoQueryCopy` is using beforehand, otherwise you are likely to get an error complaining that some ADO object cannot return multiple result sets.  I'm not sure, but I think this may be because `AdoQueryCopy.ExecSQL` cause a temporary ADO dataset to be created with the inserted rows.

The rows that are copied to `ATable` in the second database can be selected by adding a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Your advice helped me to solve my problem, thank you a lot !

Comment: In that case, please "accept" it by clicking the "tick" icon at the top left of my answer.

Answer (score -3):

if you are new on delphi
Put a TStringgrid TAdo and get all data from mdb to Gridcells
later close all ado connection from mdb.and Connect to second Db *.accdb.
idk why it is accdb?
and start adotable insert datas from grid to accdb.
if your ado couldn connect accdb so create a copy of 1st mdb and try access to save as "*.mdb".
//if you are pro there is a  //ADOTable1.SaveToFile();

Comment: If you are going to copy the records field-by-field, why bother with using a visual component to do it?  You can simply copy each field's `Value` from one dataset to the the other.  But that still leaves you with the problem of creating a destination table with the same structure as the source one, which your answer does not address.

Comment: @MartynA, *"But that still leaves you with the problem of creating a destination table with the same structure as the source one"* - OP did not mentioned this fact :/ for all I know the destination table might be already existing. and since the OP did not provide details I had no motivation to answer.